# Update struts jquery chart in pure jquery

Tags: jquery, struts, flot

This question is a little long-winded, but essentially I want to modify a pie chart in jquery that was created using the struts jquery plugin.

I have a pie chart that i created using the struts jquery plugin chart module -->> http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/ChartTag
This module is not as robust as the pure jquery implementation.  What i want to do is add a threshold and maybe the hover/click events.  There does not seem to be a way to add these to the struts jquery module.  Is there a way to use jquery to update the chart after it's already been created?

Here's my code:

```
<sjc:chart
    id="chartPie2"
    cssStyle="width: 100%; height: 400px;"
    legendShow="true"
    pie="true"
    pieLabel="true"


>
    <s:iterator value="%{mapFromStrutsAction}">
        <sjc:chartData
            label="%{key} - %{formatCurrency(value)}"
            data="%{value}"
        />
    </s:iterator>
</sjc:chart>
```

What i want to do is somehow take this chart that's created and modify it.  As I mentioned, there are things in the jquery implementation that don't seem to be available in the struts jquery plugin, like thresholds, combining slices, and hover/click effects (as found here --> http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/pie.html).

Here is my attempt, placed after the code above inside a  block, which does not seem to really seem to change anything:

```
// INTERACTIVE
    $.plot($("#chartPie2"),
    {
        series: {
        pie: { 
            show: true,
            radius: 1,
            label: {
                show: true,
                },
                threshold: 0.1
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        show: false
    }
    });

});
```

Is it possible to modify the chart in this way after it was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you try setting just the stuff you want via raw jQuery after the custom tag does its work?

If that doesn't work, then probably not. IMO the tags are for the simplest use-cases only; anything going beyond that you're better off just coding JavaScript/jQuery.

Another option is to just branch the plugin or individual tag, patch it to do what you want, then offer the patch back to the community so others can benefit.

Comment: if i try to modify the chart in raw jQuery after the fact, nothing seems to change.  it's possible that i'm not doing it correctly though.  Using the struts jquery approach is more of a directive, as i would love to just use the regular flot jquery plugin instead.  The main reason is because we want to use a map from a struts action instead of making a json call.  The struts action for the page already has the data.

Comment: You should be able to use the same methodology the S2 plugin uses--it's either setting the data directly, which you could do as well, or doing a remote call.

Comment: that is true.  The problem is that because of "tighter integration", I was directed to do it using the struts plugin.  I think that's up for debate  ;)  I made an update to my original question that includes my attempt at updating it using pure jquery.  As you can see, i left out the data property because I really only want to change the look/feel - I have a feeling my syntax is just off.  Is there an example of a chart update in jquery that was created in jquery?  I found something, but it required setting the plot function as a variable, which i don't believe i have the ability to do

Comment: My guess is that those options are only honored once, unless flot has a "redraw"-like function. There's not much syntax to actually be off. IMO you'd be better off saying more or less I said--that the tight integration is great as long as it's what you actually need to do, but it isn't, so it doesn't buy us anything. Much quicker, too.

Comment: [this example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/realtime.html) shows how to update the chart, using plot.setData() and plot.draw(), but it requires the variable 'plot' to be created initially, which doesn't look like i have the ability to do.  Looks like i might have to resort to using the jquery plugin version if i want these other features, like you said.  Thanks for your help with this!!!

Comment: Yeah, since the `$.plot(...)` call is wrapped up in the tag, without modifying it, you may not be able to get at it. You _might_ be able to sneak something in via `$.plot.plugins`, though--unclear from the docs. http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/PLUGINS.txt

Comment: (I'd still look at the $.plot.plugins bit if you're dead-set on using the tag; if must be able to access the plot; you might be able to save it to a global variable.)